# The style of the preceding tag overrides the following in IE9

Tags: html

I want to set the style on tag `li` after it is `br`.  But, when I lauch it on webview in IE9, the style on `li` also displays on the tag `br`.  Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Can you add the code of what you already did so that we can help you out?

Comment: <li>words1</li><br>words2</br>

Comment: li { color:blue}, and then words2 become blue. It's not my meaning.

Comment: In order for us to help you, please provide some extra code. From the little you have shown, you have no problems, [see this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zVclHDc1bVUSX9pWEVQL?p=preview)

Comment: @ChristopherMoore  it's no problem in google browser. but on IE 9 shows wrong. The words2 and words1 are in same line and with same color. I don't know why?

Comment: ok - that's an important point to add. I don't have IE9 available for me, but could you try swapping the `br` tag for `p` or `span`. `br` is designed to introduce a break in text, not to contain content

Comment: change `<li>words1</li><br>words2</br>` to `<li>words1</li><br />words2`